# How to change pivot of a node

Tags: swift, scenekit

I tried this

```
xxxx.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

But it does not make it centered. What is the best way of doing that with code?
[image]

Comment: are you sure initial pivot is at (-0.5,-0.5,-0.5) in localCoordinate of couch. put a small sphere in pivot point and find how much it is displaced

Answer (score 1):

Center the pivot to the center of the object, and the object to the center of the world, in Blender, Cheeatah 3D, 3D studio Max or any other suitable software and then re-export it with the pivot in the proper position. Changing the pivot in code does not have the same effect and will quite likely lead to other issues once you want to translate, rotate, scale etc. Offsetting the pivot through code is not really meant as a fix for an incorrectly placed pivot which is actually the result of the vertices having the wrong positions. Rather than trying to patch that in code, fix it properly in a 3D modeling package.

Answer (score 0):

A little confused about the question. Are you trying to center the couch on the coordinate origin? Why are you using `pivot` instead of `translation`? The `pivot` property moves the local coordinate system origin relative to the object itself (i.e. setting the upper left corner of the couch to be 0,0, instead of the center). Whereas `translation` moves the object in the scene but maintains the object's position relative to its own coordinate system. Which are you trying to accomplish?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408044-pivot

Comment: I want those arrows in the center of my node.

Comment: Is the image in your question from before you change the pivot or after? If (0, 0, 0) does not indicate the center of the couch, it might be easiest to change this in 3D modeling so that the couch vertices are defined relative to its center, then the coordinates will be centered by default. But if you want to do this on the current model, you can center the axes by setting the pivot to (couchWidth/2, couchHeight/2, couchDepth/2).